# Awesomium On Mac

Tags: macos, package, bundle, awesomium

I have developed a program that uses Awesomium on mac, and I am trying to bundle the entire thing into an Application Bundle.

I have the framework and everything packaged into the bundle where it is supposed to be, but awesomuim uses some external executables that must be present for the rendering to run (Awesomium & AwesomiumProcess)

If I place these file outside of the application bundle inside the same directory as the .app everything works fine, however I would like to be able to just deploy the single .app file containing the entier application, my question is:  Where do I have to put the additional executables so that they will run with my application (or rather so my application can run them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awesomium.framework (which contains Awesomium and AwesomiumProcess) just needs to be copied to the "Frameworks" folder of your app bundle.

From our [support documentation](http://support.awesomium.com/kb/getting-started/setting-up-on-mac-osx):

If your project is using an Application Bundle (e.g., you're creating a Cocoa Application):

1. Right-click your Application's name under Targets in XCode's Groupes & Files panel.
2. Select Add -> New Build Phase -> New Copy Files Build Phase.
3. In the dialog that appears, select Frameworks under the Destination drop-down list.
4. Close the dialog.
5. Expand your Application's list of build phases (just click the little triangle next to your Application's name under Targets to expand the list).
6. Drag and drop Awesomium.framework onto the Copy Files build phase that you just created (should be the one at the bottom of the list).
7. The Awesomium framework should automatically be copied into your Application Bundle every time you build your application.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: It would be nice if you update the documentation for the new Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Additional executables are often put into a `.app` bundle's `Resources` directory. You can get the path to such an executable using `NSBundle` (or, if the executable needs to be on the `PATH` for some reason, you can add the path to the `Resources` directory to the `PATH` environment variable when the application loads).